# C# WebBrowser Control - Function to reload image not working

Tags: c#, html

I got following html:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <img width='100%' id='testImage' src='testImg1.png'>
</html>
```

and I'm trying to reload the image with another src:

```
 public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"D:\TestData\TestData.html");

        webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
        webBrowser1.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser_Navigated);

    }

    void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;

        element.text = "function reloadGraphic()" +
                       "{ " +
                            "document.getElementById('testImage').src=\"" + @"D:\TestData\testImg2.png" + "\";  " +
                            "alert('Executed')" +
                       "}";
        head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("reloadGraphic");


    }
```

The function executes fine but everytime it ends in that:

[image: Failed Loading?]

Anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like the source of your image could be incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, but the source is correct, file is present.

Comment: And can you condirm that your javascript can access the file? Besides it being present on your hdd

Comment: ....I got the culprit: html + backslashes = not good. Used slashes instead in the path and it's working now. Damnit..wasted quite some time! (-: Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....I got the culprit: html + backslashes = not good. Used slashes instead in the path and it's working now.